# Why isn't my navigation component generating the Directions?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-gradle-plugin

I had a problem with the gradle of an already made project and had to remake the project from scratch and everything is working fine except the navigation isn't working well, it doesn't generate the Directions

I searched up for answers in other posts, but none of them works for me, and I don't know much of gradle to solve it myself, I attach all the files that *might* be involved:

Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Unscramble"
        tools:targetApi="31" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

build.gradle (Project):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.7.4' apply false
}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.4")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.unscramble'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.unscramble"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2'

    //ViewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1'

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.4"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.4"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "unscramble"
include ':app'
```

Comment: Ok so, the imports and the setup *seems* to be done correctly, the only solutions might be: 1) you haven't created any directions in the navGraph itself 2) You need to clean and rebuild your project or just invalidate the caches

Comment: I definitely have created directions, as I had them on the other project and here as well, not only that, but I tried to copy paste the old file on this project AND remaking it from scratch and none of it works, I tried cleaning and rebuilding a dozen times and nothing, and I've just tried to invalidate caches and it didn't help.